Oracle SQL - using bind variable for and or where statement
I have a query that takes user input, basically, user can decide if:
1.The filter is an 'or' or an 'and'
2. The value of said filter (using preset existing values on my_table) / :filter_bind
(as an example I'm using columns job_title and Id)
The 'or' part is working perfectly so I'm trying to use the same logic into the 'and' piece:
select count(*) from my_table
where         :my_or_and_bind = 'and' 
and
(
:filter_bind is null
or
(
instr(':' || regexp_replace(lower(:filter_bind), '\s+') || ':', ':' ||    regexp_replace(lower(job_title), '\s+') || ':') > 0
and
instr(':' || :filter_bind || ':', ':' || id || ':') > 0
)
)  

When replacing the bind filter for an existing job_title value e.g. 'vp' it works, bringing all rows with job_title 'vp' but if I add something else to the bind it stops working even if there's a matching id within the VP results e.g. 'vp:98' (job title vp and id #98).
Instead of returning the one row where job title = vp and id = 98 it returns 0 rows.
Any ideas?
Thanks

That you are having to searching with regexp and parse out strings between delimiters already indicates a data modelling problem. Redesign your table so that each piece of discrete information is a separate properly typed column and your SQL will be far less complex than it's going to be otherwise.

If you are passing vp:98 in one string then you can combine the two checks using a single LIKE for the and filter:
select count(*)
from   my_table
WHERE  (   :my_or_and_bind = 'and' 
       AND (  :filter_bind is null
           OR ':' || lower(:filter_bind) || ':'
                 LIKE '%:' || lower(job_title) || ':' || id || ':'
           )
       )
OR     (   :my_or_and_bind = 'or' 
       AND (  :filter_bind is null
           OR lower(:filter_bind) LIKE lower(job_title) || ':%'
           OR :filter_bind LIKE '%:' || id
           )
       )

However, you may be better to have separate bind variables for the job_title and for the id.
select count(*)
from   my_table
WHERE  (   :my_or_and_bind = 'and' 
       AND ( :filter_title is null OR :filter_title = job_title )
       AND ( :filter_id is null OR :filter_id = id )
       )
OR     (   :my_or_and_bind = 'or' 
       AND (  ( :filter_title is null OR :filter_title = job_title )
           OR ( :filter_id is null OR :filter_id = id )
           )
       )

